# `systemctl --host root@pc2` not working but `ssh root@pc2 systemctl` is?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

`systemctl` has a `--host` option that is meant to execute the named systemctl command on the name host. The man page suggests that this uses ssh under the hood, so it is all the more confusing to me that in my case

```
systemctl --host root@pc2 is-active docker
```

is not working (no output, exit code: `1`), but

```
ssh root@pc2 systemctl is-active docker
```

is (output: `active`, exit code: `0`).

I can't seem to find a way to debug this. Setting `-o verbose` on the systemctl command doesn't provide any more output.

Any idea what might be amiss or how to debug this?

---

Update

using `journalctl -f | grep ssh` on `pc2` I've been able to see that when `systemctl --host root@pc2 is-active docker` is run, the ssh connection seems to be successful (`Accepted publickey for root from IP-of-PC1...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command does use SSH, but it doesn't actually execute systemctl remotely – it's designed to directly talk to the remote system's D-Bus IPC channel. For this purpose it invokes `systemd-stdio-bridge` on the remote machine, which connects to the D-Bus "system bus" and relays messages back and forth. Then you have the local systemctl making API calls to remote systemd, retrieving the data over SSH and formatting it locally.

One possible problem is that your remote system *doesn't have* the D-Bus system bus running at all (i.e. there's probably no `dbus-daemon --system` or `dbus-broker --system` process). In this case, direct remote systemctl invocations would still work as it has a fallback "private" socket for talking to pid1 directly – but the systemd-stdio-bridge helper would not work as it's only designed to connect to a fully working bus.

Use `strace` to see what systemctl runs under the hood:

```
pc1$ strace -f -e execve -v -- systemctl -H root@pc2 is-active httpd
[pid 660170] execve("/usr/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "-xT", "--", "root@pc2", "systemd-stdio-bridge"], 0x7ffcd35cd548 /* 74 vars */) = 0
```

...and what sockets it's able to connect to (as root it will be using the private socket, as non-root the general system bus):

```
pc2# strace -f -e connect systemctl is-active named
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/systemd/private"}, 23) = 0
active
```

```
pc2# strace -f -e connect systemd-stdio-bridge < /dev/null
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. The dbus was running on pc2 according to `ps aux | grep dbus`, however `systemd-stdio-bridge` would always fail with exit code 1 and printing `Failed to process bus: Operation not permitted`. This was on a buildroot.org image and switching to a different version of that fixed the issue. Still somewhat inconclusive as to what the real culprit was, but I'm unblocked. Thanks again!